# Was begin() made constexpr in C++17 but cbegin() in C++14?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++14, c++17

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), `std::cbegin()` for containers was introduced in C++14 as `constexpr` - but `std::begin()`, introduced in C++11, remained non-constexpr until C++17.

Really? That seems very lopsided. What was the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The overload

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
constexpr T* begin( T (&array)[N] ) noexcept;
```

was constexpr in C++14, so `std::cbegin`, which calls `std::begin`, was also made constexpr in C++14.

For non-arrays, `std::cbegin` was not usable in constant expressions in C++14, even though the function template is still marked `constexpr`.

Comment: So, was the function template constexpr, or wasn't it? Also - why wasn't it usable?